# How to set selected option in form in html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to pass the selected option from index.html page to form.html. Now in this form there will be field which must be same which are selected in index.html page. How I will do that?

**index.html**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <label for="">Search By Services</label>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker">
            <option>Carpenter</option>                                      
            <option>Mobile SIM services</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

**form.html**

```
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">City:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" value="Bangalore" name="" placeholder="" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: That's two different pages, you'll need serverside code to capture the value of the select from a form submit, and output it as the value in the other page.

Answer (score 1):

Get the value from the first form, "POST" or "GET" it to the server preferably through server side language using sessions and use it in other form.